# Compare files on double click in Pending Changes view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there a way in visual studio to change the behavior when I double click a file in the 'Pending Changes' view.

The default behavior is, that Visual Studio opens the file in code editor, but I want that it opens the 'Compare'-Dialog with the latest version. (same behavior as in TortoiseSVN)

Comment: For anyone new coming to this thread using VS 2015+ [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40072722/5344498)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is a way to make this permanent so you don't need to shift + double-click: http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-double-click-to-diff-pending.html

**Path:**    HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<ver>\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior
**Value**:   DoubleClickOnChange (DWORD)

0 == view as the primary command (default) 
1 == compare as primary command

Comment: Love it! Works in VS2012.

Comment: This works when using Team Foundation Server as the backend, but not for Git backends. Shift-double click works though as suggested below http://stackoverflow.com/a/4396393/81949

Comment: Works without restarting Visual Studio :)

Comment: Have a look at @andrerpena answer - useful to keep it forever in handy snippets folder.

Comment: Still works in VS 2019, though I had to create all the keys "TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior"

Answer (score 71):

Do shift + double-click instead.

Comment: Noah, if I could give you more rep than +1 for this, I would.

Comment: awesome! TFS is cool, but the tortoise team have got a lot right in the usability department - some stuff TFS can learn from.

Comment: This approach is simple & works, and has the advantage in VS2013 that it will work with the Git changes window, too!

Comment: This also works in the reverse for VS2015 where compare seems to be the default double click option for git changes. Shift + Double-click opens in view mode.

Answer (score 18):

The steps from VS2017 onward are a bit different.
[VS 2017 uses its own private registry](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/11/23/some-implications-of-the-new-modular-setup-of-visual-studio-2017-for-vsx-developers/), which is stored in your AppData folder.

Steps

1. Close all visual studio instances
2. Select the HKEY_USERS node, and click File > Load Hive
3. Open privateregistry.bin which can be found at `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[*some key*]`
4. Provide a key name. Eg VS2017PrivateRegistry
5. Navigate to the following path and create a new DWORD with value of 1.

   **Path**:`HKEY_USERS\VS2017PrivateRegistry\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[*some key*]\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior`

   **Value**: DoubleClickOnChange (DWORD) 1
6. Select HKEY_USERS\VS2017PrivateRegistry
7. Click File > Unload Hive

Comment: I had this set in the public registry in VS2013, and after upgrading to 2017 I went through the above steps to add it in the private registry for VS, but behavior hasn't changed. Did you actually see that this worked, or just that it had a private registry and this is how the key could be added there?

Comment: Yes, it did work for me and colleagues that tried it.

Comment: Definitely not working for me. I just deleted, unloaded, re-loaded, and re-added the key. It'll keep bothering me so I'm bound to keep looking at it. If I ever find what's wrong, I'll report back here. Thanks.

Comment: The standard instructions worked for me in VS2017 but I am using Git.

Comment: Additional reading: https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/29/changing-visual-studio-2017-private-registry-settings/

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly in VS2019 as well (except that version is 16 instead of 15).

Answer (score 9):

## VS 2017

This PowerShell script should turn this on for the latest installed instance (adapted from [Anish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395944/compare-files-on-double-click-in-pending-changes-view/42678000#42678000))

You'll need to close all VS instances first.

```
$instanceId = $(& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -property instanceId).Trim()
reg.exe load HKLM\VS2017PrivateRegistry $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_$instanceId\privateregistry.bin
reg.exe add HKLM\VS2017PrivateRegistry\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_$instanceId\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior /v DoubleClickOnChange /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg.exe unload HKLM\VS2017PrivateRegistry
```

## VS 2015 or older

This PowerShell command should turn this on for all installed versions:

```
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\*\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior DoubleClickOnChange 1
```

Comment: This is excellent, but it didn't work for my VS 2008, which apparently doesn't include the Behavior key by default. So, this should find all installed VS entries, add the key, and then set the value:

`ForEach ($vs in Get-Item HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\*[0-9].[0-9]* -Exclude *_Config) { New-Item -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" ("Registry::" + $vs.Name + "\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior") | Out-Null }; Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\*\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior DoubleClickOnChange 1`

Comment: The * really saves time looking for the right version / config!

Answer (score 8):

### VS 2019 And Beyond (hopefully)

Building on Tereza's answer using powershell

Run powershell as adminstrator and close Visual Studio. 
(you might have to wait a couple of seconds for VS to release some files)
(if you copy paste make sure to send the last command, or else VS won't start)

```powershell
$instanceId = $(& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -property instanceId).Trim()
$versionMajor = $(& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -property installationVersion).Trim().Substring(0,2)
$year = $(& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -property catalog_productLineVersion).Trim()
reg.exe load HKLM\VS$yearPrivateRegistry $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$versionMajor.0_$instanceId\privateregistry.bin
reg.exe add HKLM\VS$yearPrivateRegistry\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$versionMajor.0_$instanceId\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior /v DoubleClickOnChange /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg.exe unload HKLM\VS$yearPrivateRegistry
```

This attempts to determine the major version as well.

Answer (score 5):

Put this on a **.reg** file and and double click it, this will make your double click compare instead of opening the file in the pending changes window.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior]
"DoubleClickOnChange"=dword:00000001
```

Make sure the Visual Studio version is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In all versions, you can:

- double click for one action
- click, then *Shift + Double Click* to perform the alternate action

In later versions of Visual Studio (including 2019 and 2022), you can also change the default double click action in the git changes window without messing around with registry changes:

- Go to the "*Git Changes*" window
- On the line where it says "*Changes*", click the three dots "..." on the right (immediately to the right of a plus button)
- Select the first option. The option will alternate between "*Compare File as Default Action*" and "*Open File as Default Action*"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDhdt.png)

Comment: This is the most up to date answer!

Comment: For some reason I did change it and I didn't know it, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You could also apply some Visual Studio keyboard short cuts for the various comparison types - Latest, WorkSpace and Previous.

See the following post: [Comparison keyboard shortcuts for Pending Changes in TFS](http://alexmg.com/comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-pending-changes-in-tfs/)

Comment: The URL has [changed](http://alexmg.com/comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-pending-changes-in-tfs/).

Answer (score 1):

Slight update for 2022, as there doesn't seem to be a vswhere.exe to pull a version number, and it's 64-bit. I haven't looked to see if there's another option to pull that, but for the once-in-an-install task, I'm okay with two steps and a manual copy/paste.

Same close Visual Studio instances and wait at least a few seconds for it to unload the registry, and open a Powershell as admin. Run this first to find your version number.

```
dir $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
```

Then add it to the $version string and run the rest below.

```
$version = "17.0_[*some key*]"
reg.exe load HKLM\VSPrivateRegistry $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$version\privateregistry.bin
reg.exe add HKLM\VSPrivateRegistry\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$version\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior /v DoubleClickOnChange /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg.exe unload HKLM\VSPrivateRegistry
```

Maybe this method will be more shelf-stable for future versions, though judging from the history of this page, I shouldn't expect that.