# Inconsistent double-click behavior in VS 2015 Team Explorer-Changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have been using VS 2015 for many months now.  Whenever I needed to view my changes in Team Explorer using Git as source control, I would simply double-click the file listed under "Changes" and it would open up the diff view.

However, over the weekend, I had to re-install VS 2015.  After doing so, I found that the double-click action now simply opened the file.  This may seem small, but it is incredibly annoying to me.

I re-installed Community and Enterprise and the results were the same.  I also tried using a [registry fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395944/compare-files-on-double-click-in-pending-changes-view), but nothing I did changed the double-click action back to open as diff view.

Not only that, but my work computer, currently using VS 2015 Enterprise, DOES have the double-click to diff view.  I imported all VS settings from that computer to the newly re-installed computer, but no luck.

This is extremely frustrating.  Not only should VS have consistency across installers/versions, it should allow for registry fixes to alleviate this issue, which apparently it used to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like the below steps will do the trick.

`Team Explorer -> Changes -> ...(Options) -> Compare File as Default Action.`

[image]

Comment: Since your issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Where are these options? I'm lost.

Comment: has this been removed from update 3? cant find that settings section in pending changes

Comment: There is a good alternative to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704412/812013

Comment: This works only for **Git** repositories. If you have **TFVC**, this option is not available and their is no "Changes" view (it's "Pending Changes" there). In this case refer to the link which Chucky posted.