# Set default action to Compare in Visual Studio 2013 Pending Changes window with TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, diff

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS for source control. When I open Team Explorer > Pending Changes and double-click on a changed file, the file opens in the editor. The only way to see my pending changes is to right-click and choose *Compare with Workspace Version*. This gets time-consuming for a long list of files.

Can I change the default double-click action to *Compare with Workspace Version*? (That seems to be the default when using Git, but not for TFS.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checked and that works:

The simple way is highlighting the file then`shift + double-click` instead.

To make the compare behavior as default, just copy/past below string in a **.reg** file and double click it to add the registry key. (Change the version accordingly based on your TFS version)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior]
"DoubleClickOnChange"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Great! This bugged me for such a long time... :)