# Visual Studio - how to ALWAYS show pending changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I've spent most of my time using Eclipse or IntelliJ with the source in a Git repository.  I've just started working with Visual Studio with the source from a TFS Server.  Version 2015 of each.

I'm not adjusting to the version control differences and am seeking help.

Eclipe / IntelliJ shows change markers in the margin.  And although this does not provide enough information about the change, it shows you where changes have been made and you can delve deeper to find further diff information.

VS / TFS shows nothing in the file window.  I don't even know a change has been made.  To know anything, I have to open the Pending Changes window.  In it I can right-click and choose 'compare with ...'.  But then when I do the same to a different file, the changes shown for the last one disappear driving me to do the same thing if I want to see it again.  Over and over ...  I find this workflow very slow.  I found [Set default action to Compare in Visual Studio 2013 Pending Changes window with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693493/set-default-action-to-compare-in-visual-studio-2013-pending-changes-window-with) that showed you can shift double-click a file to get to the diff view.  This saves a bit of time and effort.

Is there a way to improve VS / TFS so the changes to a file are always seen?   Much like the editor Track Changes https://www.codeproject.com/articles/109611/color-indicator-for-code-changes-track-changes-in - but that sticks around after a save (until commit).

[image: Visual Studio Track Changes]

I had a look through https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tfs&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance and I couldn't see anything.  Perhaps someone knows of something?

---

Adding Screenshot for comment below.  I discussed how I worked out you can see inline diffs and sometimes you can edit these.  I found out why you can't edit them.  Because the files are in `/Temp`.  Why VS creates some diffs there and others in the file location I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the Annotate option?

Comment: A 'blame' in Git parlance. No.  Its a lot of work to turn that on and you can't edit the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension in the VS Marketplace named [TFSPendingChangesMargin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlekseyNagovitsyn.TfsPendingChangesMargin). I have found it very useful but it currently only works in VS 2013 and 2015. To make this extension work with release 2 and 3 of Visual Studio 2015, you need to download the vsix from [here](https://github.com/mika76/TfsPendingChangesMargin/releases). Unfortunately, you need to disable automatic updates of this extension, or it will get updated to the version in the marketplace.

The feature I found especially useful was the ability to rollback specific changes in a file. I would love if somebody would update it to work with VS 2017.

Comment: I use VS 2015 and it failed to work - there was an exception at startup.  Pity, that would have been a perfect solution.

Comment: @HankCa I edited my answer to include a link to a working vsix.

Answer (score 1):

Manually compare files between different versions is the expected behavior.

If you mean that you want to always show the diff view for each changed file, I think that doesn't make sense. If there are lot's of files changes in a huge project, the compare views will consume much more memory and other hardware resources, that will affect the performance.

For the [editor Track Changes](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/109611/color-indicator-for-code-changes-track-changes-in) you mentioned, you can set it accordingly for your VS, (checked, it's set as default in VS 2015). We can see that, it can identify the changes in the file itself with different color marked. From this point of view, actually achieved that "ALWAYS show pending changes" before check in the changes, then changes are marked as different color in the file.

But for TFS diff views, they are for comparing between different versions. So, they are different. And I think always show the pending changes is not necessary, we just need to compare with previous versions instantly and periodically as needed.

If you want to compare all the file changes together, you can try to get/download the source of different versions to local directory/workspace, then use the compare tools such as [BeyondCompare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGAyWvstKCI) or [ExamDiffPro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8-YserQN3U) to compare the directories. All the files within the directory will be compared in each diff view.

---

**UPDATE1:**

We can set keyboard shortcuts `CTRL + ], P` to quickly navigate to "Pending Changes", then select the file in the list with `shift + double-click` to compare them.

To specify or customize keyboard shortcuts in VS:

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard 
 , then enter "**View.TfsPendingChanges**" in the "Show Command containing" text box and the desired shortcut into the Press shortcut keys box (just press the keys you want to map) and finally hit Assign.

[image]

---

**UPDATE2:**

You can also refer to this article : [Comparison keyboard shortcuts for Pending Changes in TFS](https://alexmg.com/comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-pending-changes-in-tfs/) to set the shortcuts for below comparing:

Enter the command names below into the **Show commands containing** text box one at a time:

- `TeamFoundationContextMenus.SourceControlPendingChangesSourceFiles.Compare.TfsContextPendingCheckinsCompareWithLatestVersion`
- `TeamFoundationContextMenus.SourceControlPendingChangesSourceFiles.Compare.TfsContextPendingCheckinsCompareWithWorkspaceVersion`
- `TeamFoundationContextMenus.SourceControlPendingChangesSourceFiles.Compare.TfsContextPendingCheckinsCompareWithPreviousVersion`

For each command enter your desired keyboard shortcut into the **Press shortcut keys** text box and click the **Assign** button. You can set the shortcut keys as below for each of them, that worked at my side (***Based on your shortcut settings for other actions, just do not use the duplicated shortcut with others***):

- Shift+`
- Ctrl+Shift+`
- Ctrl+Alt+`

Also as mentioned in HankCa's comment below, if you change to an Inline Diff, then you can see the difference and edit the file. When the code was executing. To get Inline Compare, you can add the Compare Files Toolbar and selected it from one of the drop downs. If you click the '**keep open**' icon on the window tab it will remain on screen and you can open multiple diffs / edit windows.

For temp diff file, it's expected behavior, when you change the files, the system will create the TFS temporary diff files in "AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp". The files all had names like "`vctmp4316_370233.cs`"

Comment: No I mean show markers in the margin so that when I'm viewing a file I can see that it is changed (and where) - just like Editor Track Changes feature.  Exactly like it but diff against your current workplace version.  I understand you can diff against other versions (such as what is on the server) and to simplify things keep diffing of those in some deep menu like it currently is.  The current workplace version is the one you will care about 90% of the time.

Comment: The Editor Track Changes is great, however it disappears when you close the file (even if you close and then immediately re-open).

Comment: What might be an ok solution is to use a sequence of keyboard shortcuts to quickly get to the diff.  `CTRL + [, P` to get pending changes and if the file has been modified it will be in the list.  Unfortunately there is no keyboard shortcut to `compare ...` but if there was this solution would be complete.

Comment: @HankCa We can set keyboard shortcuts `CTRL + ], P` to quickly navigate to "Pending Changes", then select the file in the list with `shift + double-click `to compare them. See the updated answer above.

Comment: @HankCa Have you resolved the issue by the updated answer? any update?

Comment: Andy that certainly helps. Interestingly, however, shift-double click has stopped working for me!  Absolutely no idea why.

Comment: So yes this helps, though I'm certainly not understanding the paradigm surrounding developing with VS.  Is the general consensus that this is a good thing?  It is the only IDE ive struck which does this.  i find it makes development life very slow (again, maybe I'm not understanding the paradigm).

Comment: @HankCa Yeah, for now I cannot find a better way to show the changes instantly. Set the sequence of keyboard shortcuts can improve efficiency a bit. For the  `shift + double-click` stopped working issue, pleas check if you have changed the key for the action, Reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395944/compare-files-on-double-click-in-pending-changes-view) to fix that. And if the answer helps for resolving the issue, please accept it as answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Thanks.

Comment: my shift double-click is now working (not sure if user or application error before :).  I found https://alexmg.com/comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-pending-changes-in-tfs/ via the reference you gave.That seemed to be a better solution than `shift double-click` (since I don't have to reach for the mouse).  Could you add that solution to your answer?

Comment: \@Andy-MSFT(your handle disappeared from my last post).  ALSO it seems that if you change to an Inline Diff, then you can see the difference and edit the file.  Which is nicer, though i think I've seen the ability to edit stop happening.  Perhaps when the code was executing.  To get Inline Compare, I added the Compare Files Toolbar and selected it from one of the drop downs.  If you click the 'keep open' icon on the window tab it will remain on screen and you can open multiple diffs / edit windows.  If only 1 could make this permament and remove 'Diff-'. Could you add this to your answer also?

Comment: I discussed how I worked out you can see inline diffs and sometimes you can edit these. I found out why you can't edit them. Because the files are in /Temp. Why VS creates some diffs there and others in the file location I don't know.  I posted a picture in the question.

Comment: Great thanks.  SO requires you spell out "Comparison keyboard shortcuts for Pending Changes in TFS" to be a complete answer (that post may disappear).

Comment: Thanks @Andy-MSFT.  Although it is not quite the answer i was looking for it seems that this is the closest we are going to get in Visual Studio as it currently stands.

Comment: Andy-MSFT I've changed my selected answer to the one from @JapNolt.  You should check out the extension he lists.